# NoClassDefFoundError for singleton kotlin android?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, noclassdeffounderror

I create an arr of my library module and use it in another application.

On one of the singleton class from my aar I get `NoClassDefFoundError` for its usage

This is my singleton class

```
object SharedPrefTask {

fun doSomeWork() {
    /////
}
}
```

This is the class where I use the singleton

```
class ConfigController(val mContext: Context) {
private var prefTask: SharedPrefTask = SharedPrefTask

fun fetchConfig() {
    val configs = prefTask.doSomeWork()
}
}
```

Is there something which is wrong here?
I get the exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <clinit> failed for class m0.g; see exception in other thread
   at b.a.<init>(ConfigController.kt:2)
```

Comment: Object class is called Static class... You should call Class name .function  Like this : SharedPrefTask.doSomeWork

Comment: @GobuCSG I do agree for this but I don't get how this could create an issue

Comment: private var prefTask: SharedPrefTask = SharedPrefTask
Here is the issue... You can't assign like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due obsfucation from the obsfucation of proguard
Adding the rule helped resolve this

```
-keeppackagenames com.exaple.**
```